# Proving some properties of the identity operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Here is the question:

Prove that the identity operator $$I: (C[0,1], \|.\|_{\infty}) \rightarrow ( C[0,1], \|.\|_{1})$$ is  surjective and not open.

Could anyone give me a hint on how to prove this, please?

Comment: Hint : C[0,1] is not a Banach space under L1 norm.

Comment: This is a hint for which one @user474986 ?

Comment: Well, it must not be a surprise to you that every identity map is a bijection.

Comment: @user474986 but I have different norms .... will the proof of subjectivity needs more work in that case ?

Comment: What has surjectivity to do with norms. Can you write down the definition of surjectivity ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy here is the proof:  Let $ f \in ( C[0,1], \|.\|_{1}),$ we want to show that there exists a function $g \in (C[0,1], \|.\|_{\infty})$ such that $I(g) = f.$ 

Since $f = I(f),$ then we can take $g = f.$ .... am I correct?

Comment: @Secretly Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identiy map on any set is surjective.

Let $U=\{f: \|f\|_{\infty} <1\}$. This is an open set in $(C[0,1],\|.\|_{\infty}\})$. Its image is not open: $0$ is in the image; if the image is open then there exists $r>0$ such that $\|f-0\|_1 <r$ implies $f \in U$. Choose $n$ such that $\frac 1 n <r$ and define $f(x)=1-nx$ for $x \leq \frac 1 n$, $0$ for $x >\frac 1 n$. I will leave it to you to verify that $\|f\|_1 <r$ but $\|f\|_{\infty} =1$ (so $f \notin U$).

Comment: Could you please explain the main idea you are applying ?

Comment: Are you trying to contradict the open mapping theorem?

Comment: @Secretly Open Mapping Theorem is valid when the  spaces are complete. Here the second space is not complete.

Comment: I believe you are trying to contradict the definition of an open mapping i.e. you are trying to show that there is in $(C[0,1], \|.\|_{\infty})$ whose image i.e. $I(U)$ is not open in $(C[0,1], \|.\|_1)$ ..... am I correct?